# ASP.NET 3.5, opening a popup window from a link in a popup window

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7, popup

I have a report that has an address field link that, when clicked, opens a scorecard (in a new browser window, tsow calls for IE7) for that location.  I'm now building a process that is linked to from within that scorecard that is supposed to open an identical popup window, but instead opens within the original popup.  The report is build with a stringbuilder from the C# codebehind.

The first popup opens with:

```
 sb.Append("<a href='im_sc.aspx?variable1=" + variable1 + "&variable2=" + variable2 + "&variable3=" + variable3 + "|" + variable4 + "' onclick='window.open(this.href, \"popupwindow\", \"width=880,height=650,scrollbars,resizable\"); return false;'>" + address + "</a></td>");
```

The second opens from within the popup that opens from the above link:

```
sb.Append("<a href='d_rep/ExemptionReq.aspx' onclick='window.open(this.href, \"popupwindow\", \"width=880,height=650,scrollbars,resizable\"); return false;'><u>Submit Exemption</u></a></td>");
```

Can anyone help with making the second link open a new identical IE7 window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of second window to something else than `popupwindow`.

Comment: Meh, the dangers of cut and paste.  Thanks.